# Is it possible to set per-directory extension settings for a VS Code workspace?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I work with Go code but we have various tags for the main repo I work in, and so I would like to define different tags for different directories (or files) when I test them or they are formatted-on-save.

Here's an simplistic example workspace:

```
daemon/
  manager.go -> +build !nomanagers
  nomanagersutil.go -> no tags set
cmd/
  client/
    main.go -> +build nomanagers
  server/
    main.go -> +build !nomanagers
```

This lets me build the `cmd/server/main.go` with all the code from `daemon`, but the `cmd/client/main.go` only with a subset of the code from `daemon` and is generally a very necessary and useful thing to do for this project I work on.

As such, when I have the `daemon/manager.go` file open, I would like to have the "build on save" feature not set the tag "nomanagers", but when I am in the `cmd/client/main.go` file and I use the "build on save" feature, I would like to have the `nomanagers` tag set to true, as that's how that is built directly.

I can set tags globally for the workspace with the setting

```json
{
  "go.buildTags": "nomanagers"
}
```

but then when I have the `cmd/server/main.go` or the `daemon/manager.go` file open, it won't format / build on save these files.

So, is there a way to set `buildTags` for Go specifically per file or per directory (or more generally set extensions setting per directory or per file)?

Comment: look at multi root workspace: `File` | `Add directory to workspace`. Each project in MR workspace has a `.vscode` folder with settings, tasks, and launch

Comment: ah perfect thank you that seems to be exactly what I was looking for!